# Using Middleman in Vagrant

Tags: daemon, vagrant, middleman

I'm trying to get Middleman set up to run in Vagrant, so that all I have to do is run `vagrant up` and everything will be good to go.  At the moment, I simply have Vagrant running `middleman server` as part of the provisioning steps, which actually is working, but the provisioning never really finishes then (after running `vagrant up` I don't get returned to the command line).  Is there any way I can run Middleman so that this doesn't happen?  I really just want to be able to daemonize Middleman or run it in the background or something, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is just to detach the process into background, with something like:

```
config.vm.provision "shell",
  inline: "nohup middleman server >> /vagrant/middleman.log 2>&1 &"
```

If you want to run it as the SSH user ("vagrant" by default) instead of root, add `privileged: false` option. For stopping the process you have to kill it or run `vagrant halt/destroy`.

More complete daemon setups you could take a look at for example runit.